# electronjs ActiveX printing controls chrome based

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, activex

Edge has a new future to use IE components like ActiveX with the new update:

[image]

Because edge is build on chromium and use a plugin from MeadCo ScriptX

[image]

I want to build this for chrome as well, because we have a older version of printing that use the ActiveX Printing.

its a hybrid application that is made on chromium / chrome.

With node node js and electronjs I know it is posible but how is the qeustion !

please give me some directions to get it rolling !

[image]

Don't immediately criticize my question still learning.

Comment: What exactly are you using the activex plugin to do? There might be better modern solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: we are using the print module from ActiveX for our zebra printers !  https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/How-to-Pass-through-or-use-Passthrough-for-printer-code-with-the-Zebra-Designer-Driver?language=en_US

Comment: We use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB/getDevices to print to our zebra printers.